# Azure Policy trigger for Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I have a use case where I do not want any resource to connect to my VNET except a few allowed ones.
We are designing a secured containerized environment for our customers with very strict access control policies. However, we are not seeing the policy triggered for the network join operation.

For testing purpose, I used the following policy just to capture and deny all the operations on virtual network and assigned this policy to the resource group scope where my VNET is present:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "type",
      "equals": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  }
}
```

After this policy is assigned to my resource group, I am not able to create a VNETs in my resource group, however, I am still able to join an existing VNET in this resource group.
Looks like policy is not even getting evaluated/triggered for the network join action. How can we deny this action?

Comment: The above policy only blocks VNet creation but does not deny existing VNets from joining.

Comment: Yes. I do understand that. Thanks for your response @VenkatV.

However, I am looking for a way to deny the network join action on a virtual network. My understanding is whenever any resource is requesting to join a vnet, it should call an update on the vnet resource and azure policy evaluation should get triggered when a resource is updated as per the document here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/overview#understand-evaluation-outcomes

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to deny Network Join operation with Azure Policy, but you can use Azure Network Security Group rules to restrict network traffic to and from the VNet. NSGs allow you to control inbound and outbound traffic to network interfaces, virtual machines, and other resources within your VNet.

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Policy trigger for Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action

Network join operations typically involve a resource connecting or associating with a `virtual network`, and this may not be directly governed by `Azure Policy` in the way you're expecting. Instead, network joins often fall into the realm of network security controls, where you'd use features like `Network Security Groups`, Azure Firewall, or other network-related services.

**Network Security Groups (NSGs):** : Configure NSG on your subnets to control inbound and outbound traffic.

[image]

All traffic coming from the IP address `10.0.1.0` to the specified `VNet` will be blocked. In this way, you can restrict resources to the `VNet` and allow only specific IP address ranges that are supposed to join the network

[image]

Comment: Our list of resources that connect to this Vnet is dynamic. We just provide a secured and contained environment to our customers with a resource group and they can create their own resources within this resource group. 

With the suggested approach an attacker can create another resource satisfying NSG conditions (like IP address, range, etc.) and connect to our vnet and perform malicious functions. Hence, we need to restrict vnet joins to only those resources which are part of the resource group (which is governed by our strict access policies) that we create for the customers.